# SMTP.host variable issue

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy

Here is my Issue. I'm using Delphi 5 and Indy 9. I have no option to upgrade either at the moment. I am trying to send an email via gmail, and i hard code the string as 'smtp.google.com' it works just fine. however, if smtp.host is getting the host name from a variable it fails with error 11001, and i havent been able to figure out why. I'm new using indy so i'm probably missing something silly, but i don't understand why it could accept a string as the host, but not a variable holding the string. (It's got to be a variable because i need to pass the procedure different SMTP hosts based on the user signed in. Here is the code:

```
procedure TFormEmail.SendSimpleMail(ToEmail, MyAttachment: string);
var
  Msg: TIdMessage;
  DestAddr: TIdEmailAddressItem;
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
  SSLHandler : TidSSLIOHandlerSocket;
  Attachment: TIdAttachment;
  SMTPHost1 :string;
begin
  Msg := idMessage1;
  Msg.From.Text := EmailName(My_User);
  Msg.From.Address := EmailAddress(My_User);
  msg.Subject := 'Test';//email subject
  DestAddr := Msg.Recipients.Add;
  DestAddr.Text := '';//receiver's name (optional)
  DestAddr.Address := ToEmail;//where its going
  Msg.Body.Add(edtEmailBody.text); //email body
  SMTP := IdSMTP1;
  SMTP.IOHandler := idSSLIOHandlerSocket1;
  SMTPhost1 := SMTPHost(My_User);
  SMTPhost1 := 'smtp.google.com';  
  //SMTP.Host := SMTPhost1;  //<--FAILS
  SMTP.Host := 'smtp.google.com'; //<--SUCCEEDS
  SMTP.Port := SMTPPort(My_User);
  SMTP.AuthenticationType := atLogin; //error here (2 error)
  SMTP.Username := EmailAddress(My_User);
  SMTP.Password := SMTPPassword(My_User);
  If not empty(MyAttachment) then
    Attachment := TIdAttachment.Create(Msg.MessageParts, MyAttachment);//loads Att
  Try
    SMTP.Connect;
  except
    SMTP.Connect;//refire if exception (issue with INDY)
  end;
  if useSSL(My_User) then
    SMTP.SendCmd('STARTTLS');//load TLS 
  SMTP.Authenticate;
  SMTP.Send(Msg);
  SMTP.Disconnect;//disconnect from server
end;
```

I marked the one that fails and the one that succeeds, but i don't understand what i'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please post the declarations (Type) for My_User and SMTPHost1?

Comment: SMTPHost1 is a string (its declared in the variables at the beginning of the procedure, my_user is a global variable declared in the application, it fires fine in all the other functions. even if i just say SMTPhost1 = 'smtp.google.com' and then say SMTP.host = SMTPhost1 it fails but it i put SMTP.host = 'smtp.google.com' it sends it out.

Comment: Given the code you have shown, the only way it can be failing is if `SMTPhost1` does not actually contain a valid hostname when you are expecting it to. What does the debugger show is actually in `SMTPhost1`? And why are you calling `Connect()` a second time if `Connect()` raises an exception>

Comment: as odd as it sounds. it gets called again, because the first time it runs, if its an SSL it throws up an exception, (about not opening SSL library) and then it succeeds the second time. Im looking at having to get by with this for about 6 more months, then im switching to xe2 and indy 10. you can see above where im assigning smtphostSMTPhost1 := 'smtp.google.com'; i found a work around, but its pretty shoddy design and am embarressed to post it, lol

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have more issues in one question, I can only help you with one.

I had the same issue with Connect, I simply called the Load method from IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.

Try the following:

```
SMTP := IdSMTP1;
IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load;
SMTP.IOHandler := idSSLIOHandlerSocket1;
```